# Apache Arrow Plasma Client - Can't connect to memory store (UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: java, sockets, java-native-interface, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm trying to use the Java API for Apache Arrow to connect to a memory store. I've done this in Python, successfully, using the Python API by following the guide [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/plasma.html#the-plasma-in-memory-object-store).

I've also looked at the [C++ API documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/md_tutorials_plasma.html), but it didn't help much.

[The Java Docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/org/apache/arrow/plasma/PlasmaClient.html) makes it look similar to the other documentation.

1. Make sure the plasma object store is running (usually "/tmp/plasma"
   for the examples).

   2. Create client
   3. Connect to the client by providing the object store ("/tmp/plasma"), and ("", 0) for the other two parameters.

---

However, when attempting to use the following line, I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError, that I can't find any reference to within the Apache Arrow documentation. Other solutions found of google (such as calling System.load) haven't been successful either.

> `PlasmaClient client = new PlasmaClient("/tmp/plasma", "", 0);`

A copy of my error messages can be seen below:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:org.apache.arrow.plasma.PlasmaClientJNI.connect(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)J
>       at org.apache.arrow.plasma.PlasmaClientJNI.connect(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.arrow.plasma.PlasmaClient.<init>(PlasmaClient.java:44)
>       at plas.main(plas.java:11)`

---

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you ask on the developer mailing list dev@arrow.apache.org? This is extremely bleeding edge stuff

Comment: My suggestion would be a missing native library (due to JNI) which is required.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I was doing this but the issue is quite simple, though not easy to find. In the test routines you can find an important line:

```java
System.loadLibrary("plasma_java");
val plasmaClient = new PlasmaClient("/tmp/plasma","",0);
```

The shared library `libplasma_java.so` is created when compiling the C++ extension in CMake with the option `-DARROW_PLASMA_JAVA_CLIENT=on`. In the `arrow/java/plasma/test.sh` file you can find the entire build command but this is a derived one from that file:

```sh
cd arrow/cpp
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-g -O3" \
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-g -O3" \
            -DARROW_BUILD_TESTS=off \
            -DARROW_HDFS=on \
            -DARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on \
            -DARROW_PYTHON=on \
            -DARROW_PLASMA=on \
            -DPLASMA_PYTHON=on \
            -DARROW_JEMALLOC=off \
            -DARROW_WITH_BROTLI=off \
            -DARROW_WITH_LZ4=off \
            -DARROW_WITH_ZLIB=off \
            -DARROW_WITH_ZSTD=off \
            -DARROW_PLASMA_JAVA_CLIENT=on \
            ..
make VERBOSE=1 -j4
make install
```

I just ran it and it built everythin as desired. If you want to install it somewhere simply add a prefix `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/myuser/install-here`.

If you run `System.loadLibrary("plasma_java")` it only works if the `.so` can be found somewhere on your system (such stuff is usually specified on Linux by the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). Note that this also requires `libplasma.so` and `libarrow.so` in the system path as well.